# Tensorflow gpu not able to train my Xception model

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, image-classification

I am training an Xception model with tensorflow-gpu. I am getting this error:

FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable block14_sepconv2_bn_5/moving_variance from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/block14_sepconv2_bn_5/moving_variance/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
[[{{node FusedBatchNormV3/ReadVariableOp_1}}]]
[[block9_sepconv3_bn_5/cond/else/_9661/OptionalFromValue_3/_1548]]
(1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable block14_sepconv2_bn_5/moving_variance from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/block14_sepconv2_bn_5/moving_variance/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
[[{{node FusedBatchNormV3/ReadVariableOp_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

When I reload, it gives error on a different conv layer. I have not used a gpu before so I do not know how it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share code that you have tried to execute ? It help's easy to reproduce your issue. so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I do not know what happened that day. Since then, I have added some code lines from other forums. Some worked, some did not. But I completely forgot to log it. It works fine now.

Comment: I used these lines:

from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

This helped a lot! Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been sorted. Though I am not exactly sure what happened, I think it was a memory issue. Below lines of code have helped me a lot to manipulate my memory usage:

from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

`config = ConfigProto() config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5 session = InteractiveSession(config=config)`